# How can I send a "Break" to the WinDbg backend when using IDA as a frontend?

Tags: ida, windbg

When I use WinDbg and there's some long operation, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> to *cancel* the current operation (for instance, but not limited to, cancel PDB loading). Or use this:

[image: WinDbg break]

However, whenever I use WinDbg as a backend to IDA, it simply hangs until the current operation has finished. Is there any shortcut for sending a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> to the WinDbg backend or I just have to wait for it to complete?